# What is the most elegant and fast way to do multiple replace of a string in a string, only once and from a certain position?

Tags: php, replace

I have a long string (article in a blog) that contains many images with different class names (img-0, img-1, img-2...) followed by different src=url (...) and the same string0.

```
 text1...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text2...
 <img class="img-1" ... string0>
 text3...
 <img class="img-2" ... string0>
 text4...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text5...
 <img class="img-2" ... string0>
 text6...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text7...
 <img class="img-1" ... string0>
 text8...
```

I need to replace all the string0 that follow class="img-1" by string1 and all the string0 that follow class="img-2" by string2 and so on for 3 & 4... so the result would look like this:

```
 text1...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text2...
 <img class="img-1" ... string1>
 text3...
 <img class="img-2" ... string2>
 text4...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text5...
 <img class="img-2" ... string2>
 text6...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text7...
 <img class="img-1" ... string1>
 text8...
```

What is the best approach to do that?

I have solution with preg_replace which seems to work fine for each image class:

```
 $body = preg_replace('/img-1(.*?)string0/','img-1$1string1', $body); 
 $body = preg_replace('/img-2(.*?)string0/','img-2$1string2', $body);
```

Is this bullet proof and the best solution?

Comment: In which programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single preg_replace with 2 capture groups, that you can separately use in the replacement.

```
$body = preg_replace('/\bimg-(\d+)([^<>\n]*string)0>/','img-$1$2$1>', $body);
```

echo $body;

The pattern matches:

- `\bimg-` Match `img-` preceded by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `([^<>\n]*string)` Capture **group 2**, match optional chars other than `<` `>` or a newline, followed *string*
- `0>` Match literally

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xRnovC/1) with the group values and replacements and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/e6MkZ).

Output

```
text1...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text2...
 <img class="img-1" ... string1>
 text3...
 <img class="img-2" ... string2>
 text4...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text5...
 <img class="img-2" ... string2>
 text6...
 <img class="img-0" ... string0>
 text7...
 <img class="img-1" ... string1>
 text8...
```

Comment: Thank you I understand the regex but this will not work in my case as the real strings have completely different names.  So I have to run a few preg_replace.